# Split large String in two part depending on textview size

Tags: android, textview

i want to split one large string into two part, and their size is not fixed.
i generate textview at runtime so size is different all the time,
so i want to count howmany characters is placed inside this textview.
so i format the textview correctly.
please help me
thanx in advance

Comment: What you actually wanted to do ?..i dont understand this : "so i want to count howmany characters is placed inside this textview. so i format the textview correctly"

Comment: i want to know howmany character will be  placed into textview?

Comment: After splitting the string you will get array of strings. And before displaying the string just get its length. You will come to know about the length of the string that you are going to place in TextView

Comment: i generate textview at runtime and its size is not fix. so based on that size , i want to know howmany character is fit into the textview. so based on that calculation i split the string and then after assign that string to the textview

Comment: Thats correct. But you can set text in TextView at runtime. No issues regaarding the size of textview...You can set size of textview to whatever you want instead...

Comment: my string is larger size. and i generate textview of smaller size . so i want to know howmany character is assign to the textview at runtime and remaining character is assign to the another textview

Comment: Can you please upload your code here so that we can analyze and tell you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking for is the number of characters that would 'fit' in a TextView without clipping or the need for scrolling. All you'd have to do is determine the TextView width and height, and compute the number of characters that would fit.

In pseudo-code:

```
Width = TextView Width in px
Height = TextView Height in px
row = col = count = 0
while row < Height
  col = 0
  while col < Width
    col = col + (Size of one character in px)
    count = count + 1
  row = row + (Size of one character in px)
```

count gives the number of characters that can be displayed in the TextView at a time.

Answer (score 0):

...

```
    TextView tv;
    tv.getText().length();
```

?

No, really - what are you asking? That gives you the length of the text, then you just use that variable to split things up?